# Why TextWatcher inheritor with two methods implemented, and third implemented as anonimous class method can't be converted to lambda?

Tags: java, android, lambda

I have an `abstract class` implementing `TextWatcher`, to shorten my code in cases, where only `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method needed.

This class looks like this.

```
public abstract class AfterTextChangedTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
}
```

The question is, why when I create an anonymous implementation of this class, the call of `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` can't be converted to lambda(I use retrolambda library)? Any workarounds or pattern to let it be converted to lambda?

Now the usage of this class looks like following.

```
currentPasswordInput.addTextChangedListener(new AfterTextChangedTextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                presenter.queryCurrentPw(s.toString());
            }
        });
```

**UPD:** Thanks [tamtom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321991/tamtom) for the great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47810708/6144793).

I'll put here my new code that works well to summarize everything.

So now my AfterTextChangeListener became a FunctionalInterface.

```
@FunctionalInterface//this annotation ensures you, that the class has only 
//one unimplemented method. Otherwise, the program won't compile.
public interface AfterTextChangedTextWatcher extends TextWatcher {
@Override
default public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // default keyword in method specifier allows you to add basic implementation right in the interface. In my case, this code should do nothing.
}

@Override
default public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    //now we have two methods of TextWatcher interface implemented by 
    //default. The only afterTextChange remains abstract. This allows us to 
    //consider our AfterTextChangeListener interface as abstract
}
```

}

Now our EditText fields are ready to get AfterTextChangeTextWatcher as lambda. All we need is to specify TextWatcher type as AfterTextChangedTextWatcher.

```
currentPasswordInput.addTextChangedListener((AfterTextChangedTextWatcher) s -> presenter.queryCurrentPw(s.toString()));
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but still, I can't convert the new method to lambda, because Android EditText expects to get TextWatcher interface as an argument, but not my AfterTextChangeWatcher.

Comment: yes i was wrong, forget what i said ;-(

Comment: So the solution is to use @FunctionalInterfaces from Java 8. For details watch the accepted answer.

Comment: i dont see any `@FunctionalInterface` in the answer you mention, so how can you use `addTextChangedListener` with lambda only?

Comment: It's the bottom snippet of code in the tamtom's answer. Java 8 supports default method implementation in interfaces. So If you add default implementation to all methods except one, this interface will become Functional so it will be possible to define remaining unimplemented method as lambda. 

You can use annotation @FunctionalInterface, to produce a compilation error, in case your interface will get more than one method without default implementation.

Comment: ok i see `interface AfterTextChangedTextWatcher` but how you could use it in `addTextChangedListener` method with short lambda syntax? something like `myEditText.addTextChangedListener(...)`, whats in place of `...`?

Comment: Check the updated answer. We need to narrow TextWatcher type to our custom AgterTextChangedWatcher.

Comment: ok i see it now, `(AfterTextChangedTextWatcher)` makes the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A functional interface is an interface that has just one abstract
>   method, and thus represents a single function contract.

Lambdas require these functional interfaces so are restricted to their single method. Anonymous interfaces still need to be used for implementing multi-method interfaces.

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      ...
    }
```

if you are using Java 8 
you can use multi-method interfaces with lambdas by using helper interfaces. This works with such listener interfaces where the implementations of unwanted methods are trivial (i.e. we can just do what MouseAdapter offers too):

```
interface AfterTextChangedTextWatcher extends TextWatcher
{
    @Override
    public default void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}


    @Override
    public default void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

}
```

Comment: Great answer. @FunctionalInterface was exactly what I needed!